# When append, move the previous last <li> at the end

Tags: jquery, append

I have this list:

```
<li id="1">Text</li>
<li id="2">Text</li>
<li id="3">Text</li>
<li id="4">Text</li>
<li id="5">Text</li>
<li id="6" class="last">Text</li>
```

On click, I add another `<li>` at the end with increase number of the last `<li>`.

So I end up like this:

```
<li id="1">Text</li>
<li id="2">Text</li>
<li id="3">Text</li>
<li id="4">Text</li>
<li id="5">Text</li>
<li id="6" class="last">Text</li>
<li id="7">Text</li>
```

The problem is when I append a `<li>` it moves at the end. So my question is how can I, after I append the `<li>` to move the one **with class** `.last` to the end. I cannot remove it and append it after because the values it has are set from the user.

Comment: I'm assuming you've used them for your example, but solely numeric IDs are illegal in HTML. Consider using a `data-` attribute instead.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Illegal in HTML4, valid in HTML5. :)

Comment: @JamWaffles Its for the example, even though they are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of appending, you could use insertBefore:

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $( 'span' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $ul = $( 'ul' ),
            $last = $ul.find( '.last' ),
            lastID = $last.attr( 'id' );

        $last.attr( 'id', ( +lastID + 1) );

        $( '<li id="' + lastID + '">Text</li>' ).insertBefore( $last );

    });

})( jQuery );
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RnapA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul .last').removeClass('last');
$('ul').append('<li id="'+$('ul li').length+'" class="last">text</li>');
```

Comment: My last sentence explains that the values for each are set randomly by  a user thus I cannot swap classes, or user remove by any way. Thanks